# Java swing: i called once drawString and it printed my string multiple times

Tags: java, swing, draw, paint

I'm new in java swing programming. What i'm trying to do is paint a string to a specific location in a JPanel. The JPanel is very large and so i add it to a JScrollpane, but when i draw the string it is printed not just in the specified location but also in others. 
The first image represents the bottom of the panel where i decided to draw the string and this is correct. But if you observe whole the panel you can find the string too in others locations (see second image). 
Can someone tell me why this happen? How can i prevent it?
[image]

[image]

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
class Example extends JFrame
{
    private MyPanel gg=new MyPanel();
    Example(){
        add(new JScrollPane(gg));
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    }
    public static void main(String argv[]){
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Example test=new Example();
                test.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        return;
    }
}
class MyPanel extends JPanel
{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d=(Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.drawString("HI I LOVE ELON MUSK", 90, 300035);
        return;
    }
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(500, 300060);
    }
}
```

Comment: I only see one line of text painted at the bottom. I use JDK11 on Windows 10.

Comment: seriously? did you try to scroll slowly?

Comment: The paint methods will be called as and when the JVM feels it is required. This is known (and good) behavior. Why do you see that as undesirable?

Comment: I don't think that this is undesirable. I think that is undesirable that the string appears in other locations too and not just at the bottom.

Comment: Tip: Add @camickr (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment. I am rationalizing the number of open tabs in my browser at the moment & closing this one, so if you need my further attention, don't forget to tag me. As to the problem (nice [mre] BTW), I could not reproduce the problem here, the string only appears when I scroll right to the bottom of the scroll pane. Also I can see no problem with the painting code itself. It seems to be following best practices for custom painting. Best I can guess is a glitch in the JRE being used. (shrug)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code ran fine on my Windows 10 system.  I have a Java 13 JDK that I compile at Java 8.

I made a few changes to your main class.  Maybe these changes stabilized the display.  Run my code on your system and see.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class LongJPanelExample {

    public LongJPanelExample() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Long JPanel Example");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        MyPanel gg = new MyPanel();
        frame.add(new JScrollPane(gg));

        frame.pack();
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new LongJPanelExample();
            }
        });
    }
}

class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.drawString("HI I LOVE ELON MUSK", 90, 300035);
        return;
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(500, 300060);
    }
}
```

Comment: what does the pack() method do?

Comment: @Andrea Goldoni: The pack method causes the JFrame to be sized to fit the preferred size and layouts of its subcomponents. The resulting width and height of the window are automatically enlarged if either of the dimensions is less than the minimum size as specified by the previous call to the setMinimumSize method.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack--